# HP Proliant DL360 g7

Tags: memory

I am installing 4 x 16GB memory Dimms into a ProLiant DL360 g7 server. It currently has 12GB installed with 6 x 2GB Dimms. In which slots would I install the new 4 x 16GB Dimms to get the most memory into the server considering I have the following 6 times 2GB Dimms as current and 4 times 16GB Dimms new

Comment: The existing RAM is UDIMM. You won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the existing 12GB is ECC unbuffered, then you will need to remove them in order to use the 16GB Reg-ECC DIMM sticks.

Memory population guideline for your Server: http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c02208506

For HP ProLiant DL360 G7 Server RAM: http://www.memorystock.com/memory/HewlettPackardProLiantDL360G7.html